# JAXB unable to parse ETSI schema

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I've to parse this [ETSI REM schema](http://stash.ds.unipi.gr/projects/EVEM/repos/evidenceemitter/browse/evidence-emitter-core/src/main/resources/xsd/TS02640v1_3.xsd?at=c1add2a695c90b94ac758208d13e990cae95e229). As you can see, in line 82 they have:

```
xs:element ref="xades:Any" minOccurs="0"/
```

This makes jaxb compiler crazy, since they refer schema (like Xades) which already contain Any, and in  line 166, and 212 they define additional elements like

```
xs:element name="TransactionLog" type="xades:AnyType"/
```

I compiled the schema as:

```
xjc TS02640v1_3.xsd -d test1 -p test -b binTS1.xjb  -extension
```

where the file is:

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.1"
               xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
  <jxb:globalBindings>
    <xjc:simple/>
  </jxb:globalBindings>
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="TS02640v1_3.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="eu.esens.abb.nonrep.etsi.rem"/>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='PostalAddressType']">
      <jxb:class name="PostalAddressTypeREM"/>
    </jxb:bindings> 
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='ExtensionType']">
      <jxb:class name="ExtensionTypeREM"/>
    </jxb:bindings> 
    <!--jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='EntityDetailsType']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='AnyType']">
      <jxb:class name="AnyTypeREM"/>
    </jxb:bindings-->
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

The compiler says:

```
compiling a schema...
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "eu.esens.abb.nonrep.etsi.rem.AnyType" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 8 of http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2/XAdES.xsd

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "AnyType" is generated from here.
  line 76 of http://uri.etsi.org/02231/v3.1.2/ts_102231v030102_xsd.xsd

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 8 of http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2/XAdES.xsd

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 76 of http://uri.etsi.org/02231/v3.1.2/ts_102231v030102_xsd.xsd

Failed to produce code.
```

I also tried inline (in the xsd) bindings, with the same results.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clearly shown in the logs. The type `AnyType` is declared in both of these referred schemas

```
http://uri.etsi.org/02231/v3.1.2/ts_102231v030102_xsd.xsd

http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2/XAdES.xsd
```

you will need to write the bindings to refer to one of those schemas using `schemalocation`

```
 <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="ts_102231v030102_xsd.xsd">
    jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='AnyType']">
      <jxb:class name="AnyTypeREM"/>
    </jxb:bindings
  </jxb:bindings>
```